# Redirect to main page when comming from outside url angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, angularjs-routing

I have this `angularJS` routing:

```
angular.module('diam8App', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
      }).
      when('/calculator/', {
        templateUrl: 'calculator.html',
        controller: 'calculatorCtrl'
      }).
      when('/contact/', {
        templateUrl: 'contact.html',
        controller: 'contactCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }])
```

Everything works fine, but when I'm trying to get subpage directly by url, for example `mydomain.com/contact`, then I'm recieving `HTTP 502`. I think routing doesn't work, when accessing from outside.

So my question is: is there any way to redirect user to main page, when he comes from different page (routing from main must work as it works now)? Perhaps `.htaccess` or other angular configuration is needed?

Comment: routing is done after # value

Comment: use   when('/contact',  then try again

Comment: @RohitKumar so what should I do?

Comment: replace     when('/contact/'   with when('/contact'  remove extra '/' at the end

Comment: Probably its privileges in the web servers. you can define which urls are approved from the "outside"

Comment: @ShubhamNigam how? and why? I already have `when('/contact/'`

Comment: yes ... htaccess should be set to point to app entry point. Server has no knowledge of your virtual directories created by html5Mode in angular routing

Comment: @rzysia just hit proper url from browser... Instead if you want url without # values, you should go for server side adjustment.

Comment: @charlietfl have you any idea how this htaccess should looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Everything afther the hash isn't taken in consideration by the server and angularJS will handle that.

If you use HTML5 mode, the '#' prefix will be deleted.

The '#' is deleted because of SEO, but this can be handled with the '!' prefix:
`$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');`

When using html5mode, you need to take care of routes also in backend!

Comment: Don't use html5, and add the '!' prefix. This enables SEO and problems with back end

Comment: I did this, and now when I come to main page (`domain.com`) i have `domain.com/#!/` in url, my links stop working and still got `502` after use `domain.com/calculator` ;)

Comment: Your links in your root : `/mypage` your links in your page : `#!/mypage`

Comment: I know it might be a strange approach, but since may 2014 google runs javascript when crawling pages. He is looking for this '#!', because '#' might just be an anchor

Comment: Ok it works with changed links - but what to do to redirect user propertly, when he wrote url simple 'domain.com/contact`? Now it's still `502`

Comment: You say :  I think routing doesn't work, when accessing from outside. This is not true, because the whole app is under the same url: 'domain.com', the afther #!, is angularJS job. Maybe you have to specify www.domain.com?

Comment: true, now i checked that under url `domain.com/#/contact` I can get directly the 'contact' subpage. What I need most is to know what to do to avoid `HTTP 502` when user gets url `domain.com/contact` - for example by redirecting him to main page (`domain.com`)

Answer (score 0):

Take away the '/' of `when('/calculator/',` and use this `'/calculator'` for your $routeProvider route paths instead.

Comment: doesn't help, still got `502` when use directly `domain.com/calculator`